# AngularJs memory

Tags: angularjs, memory

I have an `Angular` application that loads in only the needed `controller` / `factory` or `service` when it needs to. However i started wondering if all of these scripts eats up the memory the longer my client uses my application.

Take for instance the following example:

Client1 logs into my application here the following controllers are loaded:

```
LoginController
UserController
```

Together with these some factories and services are loaded in to store the user for furture reference.

As my Client1 goes through my system the application keeps on adding scripts but never dumping the ones it does not use.

At the last page of my application all of my `controllers`,`factories` and services has been loaded and stored in the memory however only a few is actually being used and only a few will be used again.

Should i be concerned about this once my application grows or is that just the normal procedure of `AngularJs`?

Comment: depends what app does. I have a feed reader app I leave open for days at a time. It makes requests every 10 minutes and will add/remove several hundred entries a day. It gives me far less headaches (or memory leaks) than a simple wordpress page with constant running slide show on it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like this will be the least of your concerns if your application grows. When it comes to overhead and optimization, there's a lot of issues that will be **significantly** more memory consuming than loaded javascript files.

For instance, **too many bindings** in your view, listeners you haven't removed on a $scope **$destroy** event, **caching** of API calls. I think you shouldn't really worry about this, your application would have to be way too big for this to be an issue, and when this happens, you'll be able to simply optimize the many other areas that are more worrying.

[Here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135) you have a few tips to optimize your angular app before you even take this into account.